# HTACCESS 301 Joomla to Wordpress

Tags: .htaccess

Need some help with .htaccess and 301 redirects.

Currently my website on Joomla has url's in the following format

```
http://www.example.com/indian/bombay-grill.html
```

I am moving to the wordpress platform and the theme of my choice can show to url in this way

```
http://www.example.com/restaurants/indian/bombay-grill/
```

Notice the addition of the "restaurants" and the dropped ".html" in the url. Of course this has to also work for Mexican, Thai, Vietnamese, etc.

My url's have been indexed and rank well and I am afraid changing the structure would be bad.

Is there better way than using .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hypertext Access can work, however it won't always be viable.

For example, if you have other routes that have two segments (that is not `region/restaurant`), you'll run into problems: you'd never want `about/overview.html` to redirect to `restaurants/about/overview/` (just an example), when using a generic catch-all rule.

If, however, that error will not apply to your site, then you can simply use this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/([a-zA-Z-]+).html$ restaurants/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Nonetheless, if you have only a few routes that would conflict, then you can catch those before the catch-all above, by specifying a format for each one. It may be tedious, but because of the original structure of your site, it is necessary:

```
RewriteRule ^(about/overview)\.html$ $1 [L]
```

Or, a generic catch-all, provided any non-restaurant pages have only one segment (that is, without a forward slash anywhere in the route):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-])\.html$ $1 [L]
```

Comment: +1 bombay-grill has a `-` in it, you should allow for that too. Otherwise, I like your very good explanation.

Comment: Very nice solution. Can you provide a solution for the "about/overview.html" that would go before this catch-all? How would such a case be handled?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a simple method. Glad it works for you.